# System.out.print causing latency?

Tags: java, printing, latency

I've got a simple program that I got from my Java programming book, just added a bit to it.

```
package personal;

public class SpeedTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double DELAY = 5000;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = (long)(startTime + DELAY);
    long index = 0;

    while (true) {
      double x = Math.sqrt(index);
      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if (now >= endTime) {
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    System.out.println(index + " loops in " + (DELAY / 1000) + " seconds.");
  }
}
```

This returns `128478180 loops in 5.0 seconds.`

If I add `System.out.println(x);` before the if statement, then my number of loops in 5 seconds goes down to the 400,000s, is that due to latency in the `System.out.println()`? Or is it just that `x` was not being calculated when I wasn't printing it out?

Comment: Printing to the console has got to be the worst thing you can do performance wise. IO operations takes a lot of time.

Comment: System.out.println is an IO operation and yes it can effect performance of any program

Comment: Well asked question, I don't understand the downvotes. Just because it's a trivial one for you, doesn't mean you should downvote.

Comment: For comparison purposes, you could use a `StringBuilder` and `append(x)` inside the loop, and then print it out ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you "do output" within a very-busy loop, in *any* programming language whatsoever, you introduce two possibly-very-significant delays:

1. The data must be converted to printable characters, then be written to whatever display/device it might be going to ... and ...
2. "The act of outputting *anything"* obliges the process to synchronize itself with any-and-every-other process that might also be generating output.

One alternative strategy that is often used for this purpose is a "trace table."  This is an *in-memory array,* of some fixed size, which contains strings.  Entries are added to this table in a "round-robin" fashion:  the oldest entry is continuously being replaced by the newest one.  This strategy provides a *history* without requiring *output.*  (The only requirement that remains is that anyone which is adding an entry to the table, or reading from it, must synchronize their activities *e.g.* using a mutex.)

Processes which wish to *display* the contents of the trace-table should grab the mutex, make an in-memory copy of the content-of-interest, then release the mutex before preparing their output.  In this way, the various processes which are contributing entries to the trace-table will not be delayed by I/O-associated sources of delay.